# How to fetch query string in AMP?

Tags: amp-html

In AMP, I am trying to fetch url of currently opened page. So that i can access the query paramater. like

**`example.com/ampPage.html?videoid=1234`**

i want to get the videoid from this url in **`AMP`** page.

Comment: Hi, can you add more details to your question, for example, the code block that you have tried?

Comment: @WaqasAfzal Which language are you using?

Comment: `<amp-iframe width="400" height="300"
               layout="responsive"
               sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"
               src="https://example.com?videoid=1234">    
 </amp-iframe>`

what i want to do is to replace videoid value with currently opened url like
`example.com/ampPage.html?videoid=98562`  @MForMarlon

Comment: amp-html @BachchaSingh

Comment: @WaqasAfzal in amp-html you can not do, in php you can use <?php echo $_GET['videoid']; ?>

Answer (score 1):

AMP's [variable substitution](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-var-substitutions.md#query-parameter) provides access to query parameters. However, this doesn't work in combination with `amp-iframe`. As a workaround it might be possible to use an `amp-list` and then render the iframe inside the `amp-list`.

A better approach would be to render the page server-side instead.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian Benz . Your suggestion really helped me out. Its working